# Java AES T-Tables Implementation

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, aes

I am trying to implement an encryption function that uses the AES T-Tables implementation.

I am quite sure that my roundKeys are correct.
I also know that the initial round key addition in the following code is correct.

So there must be an error in the main rounds, but i am not sure what went wrong. I have narrowed it down to the following problems:

1. The logic I use to lookup in the t-tables in each round:

```
temp[i] = T0[(state[i] >>> 24) & 0xFF] ^
                        T1[(state[(i + 3) % 4] >>> 16) & 0xFF] ^
                        T2[(state[(i + 2) % 4] >>> 8) & 0xFF] ^
                        T3[state[(i + 1) % 4] & 0xFF] ^ roundKeys[round][i];
```

That seems correct? I followed the descripton in [Rijnadel Proposel on page 18](https://csrc.nist.gov/csrc/media/projects/cryptographic-standards-and-guidelines/documents/aes-development/rijndael-ammended.pdf).

2. Maybe I am using the wrong t-tables for looking up. I am not sure which ones are correct. I found T-Tables in the [bouncy castle implementation](https://github.com/bcgit/bc-java/blob/main/core/src/main/java/org/bouncycastle/crypto/engines/AESFastEngine.java) and then i found some different tables in the [Go implementation](https://go.dev/src/crypto/aes/const.go).

They are both different, but i have tried my code with both and it doesnt work.
Which of these tables are the correct ones?

```
public byte[] blockEncryption(byte[] plaintext, int[][] roundKeys) {
        // Convert plaintext bytes to state matrix
        int[] state = new int[4];
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            state[i] = ((plaintext[4 * i] & 0xFF) << 24) |
                    ((plaintext[4 * i + 1] & 0xFF) << 16) |
                    ((plaintext[4 * i + 2] & 0xFF) << 8) |
                    (plaintext[4 * i + 3] & 0xFF);
        }

        // Initial round key addition
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            state[i] ^= roundKeys[0][i];
        }

        // Main rounds
        for (int round = 1; round < 10; round++) {
            int[] temp = new int[4];
            for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
                temp[i] = T0[(state[i] >>> 24) & 0xFF] ^
                        T1[(state[(i + 3) % 4] >>> 16) & 0xFF] ^
                        T2[(state[(i + 2) % 4] >>> 8) & 0xFF] ^
                        T3[state[(i + 1) % 4] & 0xFF] ^ roundKeys[round][i];      
            };System.arraycopy(temp, 0, state, 0, 4);
        }

        // Final round (without MixColumns)
        byte[] ciphertext = new byte[16];
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            int word = roundKeys[roundKeys.length - 1][i];
            ciphertext[4 * i] = (byte) (S[(state[i] >>> 24) & 0xFF] ^ (word >>> 24));
            ciphertext[4 * i + 1] = (byte) (S[(state[(i + 3) % 4] >>> 16) & 0xFF] ^ (word >>> 16));
            ciphertext[4 * i + 2] = (byte) (S[(state[(i + 2) % 4] >>> 8) & 0xFF] ^ (word >>> 8));
            ciphertext[4 * i + 3] = (byte) (S[state[(i + 1) % 4] & 0xFF] ^ word);
        }
        System.out.println("Endzustand: " + intArrayToHex(state));

        return ciphertext;
    }
```

Comment: Ok. I read falsly. Big-endian Little-endian.